# Point of presenter in clean architecture with MVC

Tags: clean-architecture

Reading the book clean architecture, I trying to figure out the best way to use the presenter in MVC. Since there is no code associated I'm having a hard time finding the need for a presenter.
It seems to me that the controller in MVC can be used for both controller and presenter. The usecase returns a model that you convert to a viewmodel in the controller.
If the presenter is to be used at all, you would just return the return model to the controller and call the presenter class from there. Any issues with this or can someone explain how this works in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

When implementing Clean Architecture in e.g. Asp.Net MVC what u describe is a perfectly valid, simple and pragmatic approach. Presentation logic is clearly separated from business logic (use cases) and the control flow is according to Uncle Bob's Dependency Rule.

In fact I still follow this approach in my Clean Architecture based Asp.Net MVC projects.

I recently discussed the topic in more depth in a blog post: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/